# PowerPoint Add-In Setup Project Does Not Update

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, setup-project

I have been developing a .Net PowerPoint Add-In in Visual Studio 2013.

The project was originally created in Visual Studio 2010, utilizing the Setup Project. I recently migrated the project to 2013 and installed the 'Visual Studio Installer Projects" extension. 
*I do not believe this is causing the problem, however it should still be noted.*

I don't understand why, but when I generate updated Setup.exe and msi files, the previous version is not replaced. My colleagues and I are forced to manually remove the previous version before running the setup file or these updates are not made.

What I do on my Project:

- I make essential changes to my project
- I update the Publish Version of my project
- I clean and re-build my    project
- I check 'DetectNewerInstalledVersion' is set to TRUE on my Setup Project
- I check 'RemovePreviousVersions' is set the TRUE on my Setup Project
- I check that my Primary Output and application folder contains the correct updated files
- I update my Setup Project's Version number; which I understand updates the Product Code. The Upgrade Code is left unchanged.
- I then re-build my Setup Project

Once this process is complete, I run the Setup.exe file. The problem is then visible; as my Add-In does not update and my changes do not exist.

I then:

- Check the Add-In's version number on the control panel; it correctly matches that of the latest Setup Project
- Check the manifest file installed in the user's AppData/Roaming/Company/Product folder; this correctly matches that of the latest project version

However, if anybody uninstalls the Add-In and then uses the Setup.exe; the changes exist and everything works as expected.

I can only assume that there is a fundamental step or procedure that I have missed - do you have any suggestions on what this might be?

Do you know how I should troubleshoot this problem from here?

Answer (score 1):

Okay - I have just resolved this problem!

I researched for a good hour before posting this question; typically I resolved it straight after! Apologies for that.

Simply put; I had to update the Assembly Information (version numbers) and Clean the project - instead of updating the publish version number.

Sounds obvious now I think about it.

To all those who stumble upon this: I hope you have a fantastic day! :)

Comment: You actually need to update only the file version, it just happens to default to assembly version. If you don't need to change assemblyversion just increment AssemblyFileVersion.